# How to create version number in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops

I have one web project. Pipeline in Azure DevOps, instance in GCP. If I canceled pipeline in Google App Engine create version and i must pay for this.... How to set up a pipeline or Google App Engine so that the version in Google is recorded only when the pipeline is successfully completed

Comment: Can you share on which version of App Engine you are (flex or standard)? and How do you deploy your service in azure devops pipeline?

Comment: Hi @kostukp96, how are things going? Are the explanation and suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please check it. Feel free to tell us if you have any question about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to deploy a version of your APP to Google App Engine using a pipeline on Azure DevOps, if the deployment step itself is failed, normally the new version may not be deployed to App Engine. You just need to retry the pipeline.

However, if the deployment step has completed successfully, but one of the subsequent steps or jobs is failed and caused the pipeline failed, the new version has been deployed to App Engine. In this situation, you may not able to redeploy the same version to App Engine.